# BigQuery using firebase-analytics events getting error

Tags: android, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am new to BigQuery using firebase-analytics and trying to fetch data from the created event with custom param.

> Getting error at line 13 on
>   UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties) user_properties
>   Error : Unrecognised name:user_dim; Did you mean by user_id?

I have tried with mentioned code.

```
SELECT
  user_properties.value.value.string_value AS total_price,
  AVG((
    SELECT
      SUM(value.string_value)
    FROM
      UNNEST(event_dim),
      UNNEST(params)
    WHERE
      key = "quantity")) AS quantity
FROM
  `uniorder-prod.analytics_200255431.events_*` t,
  UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties) user_properties
WHERE
  event_name = "total_consumption_res"
  AND user_properties.key = "total_price"
```

I expect 2 columns one for total_price and another for the quantity which will some all quantity data.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I was doing mistakes so If you want the result you can refer to this answer.**

```
//Query to run on BigQuery Console, you can change event param as per your 
//need

SELECT
  param2.value.string_value AS item_name,
  SUM(param3.value.double_value) AS quantity,
  SUM(param4.value.double_value) AS total_price
FROM
  `uniorder-prod.analytics_200255431.events_*`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS param1,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS param2,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS param3,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS param4
WHERE
  event_name = "total_consumption_res"
  AND param1.key = "user_id"
  AND param1.value.int_value = 118
  AND param2.key = "item_name"
  AND param3.key = "quantity"
  AND param4.key = "total_price"
GROUP BY
  item_name
ORDER BY
  total_price DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be created for the old database schema, it has been flattened a bit since then so you no longer need to unnest user_dim (or event_dim) to access user_properties.

Check out the new schema here: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en

Comment: I am not able to understand and fix my issue from the given link.

Comment: You are doing UNNEST on something that does no longer exist (user_dim), i.e. your query is outdated. I'm not going to rewrite your query for you, sorry.

Comment: I have fixed the issue, Anyways Thanks :)